# bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, autowired

### Introduction

I was using the following in my POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

AND

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Now I have the following:**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

AND

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

### Errors:

```
 Error:(34, 21) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class TemplateProcessingParameters
      location: package org.thymeleaf
    Error:(37, 38) java: package org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver does not exist
    Error:(49, 38) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class TemplateResolver
      location: package org.thymeleaf.templateresolver
    Error:(179, 65) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class IResourceResolver
      location: class eu.europa.ec.themis.sgtemplateservice.MbakTemplateServiceApplication
    Error:(187, 56) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class TemplateProcessingParameters
      location: class org.mbak.MbakTemplateServiceApplication.InMemoryResourceResolver
    Error:(168, 62) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class TemplateResolver
      location: class org.mbak.MbakTemplateServiceApplication
```

### Added the following dependency:

I added the following and my application builds:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

### Current Error:

So now I am getting the following error when I start the application:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.mbak.MbakServiceApplication$ThymeleafTemplateEngine required a bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' in your configuration.
```